# How to register a vue compoent correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to port this snippet into a reusable vue component:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="control-section">
        <div id='content' style="margin: 0px auto; width:350px; padding-top: 40px;">
            <span id="contentText">React top expert of this week is
            <ejs-dropdownlist id='employee' :dataSource='data' :fields='fields' :popupHeight='height' :width='width' cssClass='ddl-inlinecss' :value='value' :popupWidth='popupWidth' :placeholder='watermark'>
            </ejs-dropdownlist>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<style>

    .ddl-inlinecss.e-ddl .e-input-group-icon.e-ddl-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    .ddl-inlinecss.e-ddl .e-control.e-dropdownlist.e-input {
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: 500;
        margin: -5px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    .material .ddl-inlinecss.e-ddl .e-control.e-dropdownlist.e-input {
        margin: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    }

    .bootstrap .ddl-inlinecss.e-ddl .e-control.e-dropdownlist.e-input {
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-control-wrapper.e-ddl::before,
    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-control-wrapper.e-ddl::after {
        content: none;
    }

    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-control-wrapper.e-ddl,
    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-control-wrapper.e-ddl:hover,
    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-ddl.e-input-focus,
    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-ddl.e-input-focus::before,
    .ddl-inlinecss.e-input-group.e-ddl.e-input-focus::after {
        border-width: 0px;
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
        box-shadow: none;
    }
</style>
<script>
import Vue from "vue";
import { MultiSelectPlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";
import { Query } from '@syncfusion/ej2-data';
import * as data from './dataSource.json';

Vue.use(MultiSelectPlugin);

export default Vue.extend ({
    data: function() {
        return {
            fields: { text: 'Name'},
            height: '220px',
            width: '63px',
            popupWidth: '140px',
            value: 'Michael',
            watermark: 'Select an employee',
            data: data['employees'],
        };
    }
});
</script>
```

I therefore put all of the code above into a file called "InlineDropdown.vue" (you can check the example here: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/vue/demos/#/material/drop-down-list/inline.html)

My projects hirachy looks like this:

```
|-- src
        |-- App.vue
        |-- main.js
        |-- router.js
        |-- assets
        |   |-- fonts
        |   |-- scss
        |-- components
        |-- directives
        |-- layout
        |-- pages
        |   |-- components
        |   |   |-- **InlineDropdown.vue**
        |   |-- **index.vue**
        |-- plugins
```

Within the `index.vue` file I am importing the InlineDropdown component via `import InlineDropdown from "./components/InlineDropdown";`

When runnin `npm run serve` I am getting presented with the text of the component ("React top expert of this week is"), but not with the content of the  `<ejs-dropdownlist>`.

The error log within my browsers terminal tells me that:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <ejs-dropdownlist> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <InlineDropdown> at src/pages/components/InlineDropdown.vue
       <Index>
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

I can't see where I am declaring the component wrong. Can anybody help please?

The full code can be found here:
https://github.com/Shoxc/vue-now-ui-kit-master

This is the place where I want to add the component:
https://github.com/Shoxc/vue-now-ui-kit-master/blob/2155e6e5217d42da5829526a2c974d91051de3d3/src/pages/Index.vue#L14

This is the file for the component:
https://github.com/Shoxc/vue-now-ui-kit-master/blob/main/src/pages/components/InlineDropdown.vue

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html

i think you will need to add it to a `components` object field

`import myCustomComp from '../'
export default ...{ components: {MyCustomComp}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is the [usage of `Vue.use()` from `InlineDropdown.vue`](https://github.com/Shoxc/vue-now-ui-kit-master/blob/2155e6e5217d42da5829526a2c974d91051de3d3/src/pages/components/InlineDropdown.vue#L56). Vue plugins should be installed *before* mounting the app so that the plugin's effects are available to the rest of the app. This particular plugin (`MultiSelectPlugin`) registers `MultiSelectComponent` globally.

So, the following code should be moved to `main.js` before the app mounts:

```
// InlineDropdown.vue
// REMOVE THIS:
//import { MultiSelectPlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";
//Vue.use(MultiSelectPlugin);

// main.js
import { MultiSelectPlugin } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";
Vue.use(MultiSelectPlugin);

new Vue(/*...*/)
```

Alternatively, you could [locally register the component](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) in `InlineDropdown.vue`. However, be aware that `ejs-dropdownlist` is  actually defined in `DropDownListComponent`, not `MultiSelectComponent`:

```js
// InlineDropdown.vue
import { DropDownListComponent } from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-dropdowns";

export default {
  components: {
    DropDownListComponent,
  }
}
```

I also noticed that `InlineDropdown.vue` is imported, but [not registered in the `components` option of `Index.vue`](https://github.com/Shoxc/vue-now-ui-kit-master/blob/2155e6e5217d42da5829526a2c974d91051de3d3/src/pages/Index.vue#L85). Make sure to add `InlineDropdown` to `components`:

```js
// Index.vue
export default {
  components: {
    InlineDropdown,
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To register this component globally, you can import the .vue file into your main.js , then use
Vue.component() method to register it.

For example:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
//...some code if any 
//...some more code etc.
import inlineDropdown from "./pages/components/InlineDropdown"

//...
Vue.component('ejs-dropdownlist',inlineDropdown)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but sadly, this runs into another error, so I cannot confirm wether this helps:

vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4500 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at createComponentInstanceForVnode (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3293)
    at init (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:3133)
    at createComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6022)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5969)
    at createChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6097)
    at createElm (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:5998)
    at createChildren (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6097)
    at createElm (vue.runtime [...]

Comment: I updated the variable name, it might cause errors when it is the same as the Component's name.